# Can I use a directive as the view in an Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question comes from the following scenario:

On the homepage to my site, I want to have an animating picture gallery (pretty simple, images will be animated with javascript).

So, I wanted to include a view that has the gallery, and the necessary javascript to perform the animations.

At first I was going to include the html for the photos as a view, and then specify the javascript in a function so it would look like this:

**App.js:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/gallery.html',
            controller: 'GalleryControl'
          }))
```

**Gallery.html:**

```
<p ng-init="anim()">Welcome to my gallery </p>
<img id="one" src=''>
<img id="two" src=''>
```

**GalleryControl:**

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('GalleryControl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.anim = function () {
      var one = document.querySelector('#one');
      var two = document.querySelector('#two');
      // Perform the javascript animation
    }
```

But I have been told that that modifying the dom from the controller is not a good idea.  So, my question is, what is the best way to approach the problem? It seems like using a directive would be the best way, but, if that is the case, then the `template` specified in the `$routeProvider` is literally just the directive.

Something like this:

**Gallery Directive:**

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('gallery', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div><img id="one"> <img id="two"></div>',
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        var one = document.querySelector('#one');
        var two = document.querySelector('#two');
        //Perform animation here
      }
    };
  });
```

- Is this common / acceptable?
- If so can I just specify the `template` or `templateUrl` as a directive?

Comment: you should use directives. They dont need `url`, you place directive over a dom element and you can access it and all their childs elements as well.

Comment: nothing wrong with a template also being a directive